# Jest is not recognising where the tests are located hence cannot run tests

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ts-jest

I am updating a projects and would like to run all tests inside a root folder called test for a nestjs typescript project.

Here is a picture of the folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure Image]

Here us my current jest-e2e.json file:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "rootDir": "./test",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": "*.spec.ts",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@helper/helper/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../libs/helper/src/$1",
    "@helper/helper": "<rootDir>/../libs/helper/src",
    "@appTests/appTests": "<rootDir>/../test"
  }
}
```

Here is the error message I am experiencing:

> No tests found, exiting with code 1
> Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
> No files found in /Users/mayurkale/Development/reaper-financial-backend.
> Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
> To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
> Jest Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
> Files: "/Users/mayurkale/Development/reaper-financial-backend/test/app.tests.spec.ts"

I tried out different folder locations structures with the jest conf in order to match the correct path.

I am expecting that the jest config is incorrect and needs updating to something that works.

Comment: _Where_ is the `jest-e2e.json`?

Comment: inside the test folder

Answer (score 0):

As `jest-e2e.json` is in `./test` the `rootDir` should be set to `./` so thast jest searches using the regex matcher *from* the `rootDir`, which has a prefix value set to the path to the config file

Comment: It didn't go through.

Comment: Just generated a new project basic using the nestjs cli and it seems to be an issue, if you could try that on your end and just write a basic test see if it runs

Comment: Works fine in a `nest new` and in a `docker run -it node:latest` setting. Config is found in `./test` and `rootDir` is properly set to`'.'`